# Download .dat file from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to write a code to download file from the server, the path is correct but the file isn't downloading when I click it.

The delete code works properly which looks like this:

```
protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    File.Delete(filePath);
    GenerateDownloadLinks();
}
```

However the download isn't starting the download (debugging runs through entire code):

```
protected void ButtonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + name);
    response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    response.TransmitFile(path);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
```

The file I am downloading is a .dat file. I tried changing and adding the configurations but with no luck

Comment: Well if you delete a file before generating download links, what do you expect those links to do?

Comment: You dont send the length, it probably isnt working because it thinks it should be zero

Comment: @BugFinder TransmitFile closes the connection, so you won't need a `Content-length` header.

Comment: @CodeCaster the delete and download is two different codes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @CodeCaster its only really worked for me if I sent length...

Comment: @CodeCaster also the generatedownloadlink is just the databind code

Comment: @BloopieBloops It perfectly worked for me.. Copied the exact code.. hardcoded the path to my local file. Can you debug and check whether you are getting the exact path ?

Comment: @Balaji hi, yes it's getting the full path. Could it be permission related? But the file can be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was update panel related, my datalist was inside an update panel